# How to set custom metadata for Google Cloud Storage using JSON?

Tags: json, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I am trying to add custom metadata to all uploads from my site to GCS.

I found something but I can't get it to work, in the Service Account JSON I added:

```
  "metadata":  {
   "customMeta": "text here"
```

}

But it is not working, am I missing something here?
Thannks.

UPDATE

I am using Wordpress and a plugin called WP-Stateless, I asked the plugin author and he directed me to [link] (https://github.com/wpCloud/wp-stateless/blob/v2.2/lib/classes/class-utility.php) I tried adding a couple of lines, but after I saved it and tried uploading something, I checked the GCS console and there is no new metadata.

```
/* Add Google Storage metadata to our attachment */
          $fileLink = $bucketLink . '/' . ( !empty($media['name']) ? $media['name'] : $file );
          $cloud_meta = array(
            'id' => $media[ 'id' ],
            'name' => !empty($media['name']) ? $media['name'] : $file,
            'fileLink' => $fileLink,
            'storageClass' => $media[ 'storageClass' ],
            'mediaLink' => $media[ 'mediaLink' ],
            'selfLink' => $media[ 'selfLink' ],
            'bucket' => ud_get_stateless_media()->get( 'sm.bucket' ),
            'object' => $media,
            'sizes' => array(),
            'newDATA' => $_newData[ 'some text' ],
          );
```

But I uploaded something and check GCS but there was now newDATA some text in the metadata for the file I uploaded.

Comment: I found this as well '{"name": "myObject", "metadata": {"foo": "bar"}}' but I don't know which is the right way.

Comment: I am using Wordpress and a plugin called WP-Stateless, I asked the plugin author and he directed me to [link] (https://github.com/wpCloud/wp-stateless/blob/v2.2/lib/classes/class-utility.php) I tried adding a couple of lines, but after I saved it and tried uploading something, I checked the GCS console and there is no new metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that worked for me (notice the metadata within metadata)

```
const file = bucket.file(filename);     
await file.save(JSON.stringify(data), { metadata: { metadata: { user: 'user1' }}});
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) says, request body can have `metadata` field with JSON object having key/value pairs for metadata. Or `metadata.key` fields with specific values:

> metadata - object - User-provided metadata, in key/value pairs.
>
> metadata.(key) - string - An individual metadata entry.   writable